# Table not rendering as exepected in Latex Overleaf

Tags: tables, tabularray

I am working on a table in latex. I have used `tabularray` package in overleaf. However, in header text is missing.
I am sharing the code I have tried and output generated.

```
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{Characteristics of Training and Testing Data\label{tab:table4}}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{p{0.05\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth} p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth} p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth} }
\hline
\SetCell[c=6]{c} {Training Data} & & & & &\SetCell[c=5]{c}{Testing Data}\\
\hline
Zone & Mean(cm) &   Std(cm) & Max(cm) & Skew & Kurtosis &   Mean(cm) &  Std(cm) & Max(cm) & Skew & Kurtosis \\
\hline
Zall &  44.08 & 37.44&  373.3&  2.48&   9.71&   54.23&  41.76&  325.1&  2.03&   6.19\\
\hline
Z1& 74.52&  32.23&  157.4&  -0.17&  -0.42&  82.9&   26.26&  137.5&  -0.97&  0.38\\
\hline
Z2& 13.20&  10.37&  50.80&  1.42&   1.34&   12.06&  9.91&   53.34&  1.95&   4.64\\
\hline
Z3& 37.25&  22.18&  109.22& 0.24&   -0.58&  46.67&  26.31&  208&    0.3&    -0.03\\
\hline
Z4& 36.05&  16.11&  88.9&   -0.03&  -0.37&  40.69&  21.48&  78.75&  0.13&   -1.03\\
\hline
Z5& 35.95&  20.21&  160.02& 0.76&   0.97&   41.57&  21.79&  170.2&  1.21&   3.17\\
\hline
Z6& 59.46&  56.26&  373.3&  1.60&   2.87&   75.05&  58.31&  325.1&  1.20&   1.52\\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
       \item [*]Note: In tha table Std, Max indicated standard deviation and maximum of snow depth observations in a given zone.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end {table*}
```

As you can see, the header row text, as well as footnote are also went wrong in alignment.

Output is as below:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). As your question is not about `latex3` I removed that tag.

Comment: Add another `&` after `\SetCell[c=6]{c} {Training Data}`. There are currently only 5 instead of 6.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the `talltblr` environment from `tabularray`, which combines both `tblr` and `longtblr` and works similarly to `threeparttable`.

I added `siunitx` to help with formatting numbers. However, because the table is wide, I also propose to use `sidewaystable` instead of a regular `table`

Here's the table

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx,booktabs}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

The reference to the table~\ref{tab:table4}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
  \centering
  \begin{talltblr}[
      caption = {Characteristics of Training and Testing Data},
      label = {tab:table4},
      note{*} = {Note: In tha table Std, Max indicated standard deviation and maximum of snow depth observations in a given zone.},
    ]{
      width = \linewidth,
      stretch = 1.15,
      colspec = {
        X
        *2{Q[si={table-format=2.2},c]}
        Q[si={table-format=3.2},c]
        *2{Q[si={table-format=-1.2},c]}
        *2{Q[si={table-format=2.2},c]}
        Q[si={table-format=3.2},c]
        *2{Q[si={table-format=-1.2},c]}
      },
      row{1,2} = {guard},
      hline{2} = {2-6}{leftpos=-0.5, rightpos=-0.5, endpos},
      hline{2} = {7-11}{leftpos=-0.5, rightpos=-0.5, endpos},
    }
    \toprule
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Zone & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Training Data & & & & & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Testing Data & & & & \\
    & Mean(cm) &   Std(cm) & Max(cm) & Skew & Kurtosis &   Mean(cm) &  Std(cm) & Max(cm) & Skew & Kurtosis \\
    \midrule
    Zall & 44.08 & 37.44 & 373.3  &  2.48 &  9.71 & 54.23 & 41.76 & 325.1  &  2.03 &  6.19 \\
    Z1   & 74.52 & 32.23 & 157.4  & -0.17 & -0.42 & 82.9  & 26.26 & 137.5  & -0.97 &  0.38 \\
    Z2   & 13.20 & 10.37 &  50.80 &  1.42 &  1.34 & 12.06 &  9.91 &  53.34 &  1.95 &  4.64 \\
    Z3   & 37.25 & 22.18 & 109.22 &  0.24 & -0.58 & 46.67 & 26.31 & 208    &  0.3  & -0.03 \\
    Z4   & 36.05 & 16.11 &  88.9  & -0.03 & -0.37 & 40.69 & 21.48 &  78.75 &  0.13 & -1.03 \\
    Z5   & 35.95 & 20.21 & 160.02 &  0.76 &  0.97 & 41.57 & 21.79 & 170.2  &  1.21 &  3.17 \\
    Z6   & 59.46 & 56.26 & 373.3  &  1.60 &  2.87 & 75.05 & 58.31 & 325.1  &  1.20 &  1.52 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{talltblr}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @Celdor answer (+1):

- Except the first column are used `X` columns. By this the width if table us equal `\textwidth` and columns with with numbers have equal width.
- Text in the second row is vertical centered.
- Rows in table body are grouped in pairs (for easely reading).

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption={Characteristics of Training and Testing Data},
  label={tab:table4},
remark{Note} = {In the table Std, Max indicated standard deviation and maximum of snow depth observations in a given zone.}        ]
    {colspec={@{} Q[l] *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]} 
                            X[c, si={table-format=3.2}]
                       *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2}]}
                       *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]}
                            X[c, si={table-format=3.2}]
                       *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2}]} @{}},
     row{1,2} = {c, m, guard},
     row{odd [3-Y]}={rowsep=-4pt}
    }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Training Data
        &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Testing Data 
                            &   &   &   &                           \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-6}\cmidrule[l]{7-12}
Zone    & Mean (cm) & Std (cm)  & Max (cm)  & Skew  & Kurtosis 
        & Mean (cm) & Std (cm)  & Max (cm)  & Skew  & Kurtosis      \\
    \midrule
Zall    & 44.08     & 37.44     & 373.3     &  2.48 &  9.71
        & 54.23     & 41.76     & 325.1     &  2.03 &  6.19         \\
Z1      & 74.52     & 32.23     & 157.4     & -0.17 & -0.42
        & 82.9      & 26.26     & 137.5     & -0.97 &  0.38         \\
Z2      & 13.20     & 10.37     &  50.80    &  1.42 &  1.34
        & 12.06     &  9.91     &  53.34    &  1.95 &  4.64         \\
Z3      & 37.25     & 22.18     & 109.22    & 0.24  & -0.58
        & 46.67     & 26.31     & 208       & 0.3   & -0.03         \\
Z4      & 36.05     & 16.11     & 88.9      & -0.03 & -0.37
        & 40.69     & 21.48     & 78.75     & 0.13  & -1.03         \\
Z5      & 35.95     & 20.21     & 160.02    &  0.76 &  0.97
        & 41.57     & 21.79     & 170.2     & 1.21  &  3.17         \\
Z6      & 59.46     & 56.26     & 373.3     &  1.60 &  2.87
        & 75.05     & 58.31     & 325.1     & 1.20  &  1.52         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end {table*}
\end{document}
```